# Is it possible to execute multiple release:perform with different profiles without having to execute release:prepare again?

Tags: maven-2, maven-release-plugin

I have a POM file for a project that defines different **classifiers** for a project depending on the environment (test, production, development).

I would like to execute one time **release:prepare** and then execute **release:perform** for each environment to generate the corresponding package file.

The problem is that after the first call to **release:perform** it removes the metadata generated by **release:prepare**. I think it is calling **release:clean**.

How can I prevent cleaning up this metadata in order to execute **release:perform** with different profiles without having to execute **release:prepare** again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the clean goal is fixed in the perform lifecylce, the only way around it seems to run maven with -DdryRun=true

See here:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/release/tags/maven-release-2.1/maven-release-manager/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/shared/release/DefaultReleaseManager.java?view=markup from line 266 ...